# PUT request not going through to mongdb

Tags: node.js, express

I created a put request and when I use postman to try and update the email field in my user table, I get `Cannot PUT /api/user/5dab49630sdfsd3025a09d31d`
I'm pretty new to nodejs and expressjs so I apologize if it's something simple. It might be how I'm making PUT request in Postman. I'm not really sure how else to pass the email value though.

Postman PUT request
`http://localhost:3000/api/user/5dab496305de3025a09d31d/?email=newemail@gmail.com`

```
app.put('/api/user/email/:id', (req, res) =>
User.update(
 {email: req.body.email},
 {where: {id: req.params.id}}
  ).then( user => {
  console.log(user);
  res.json(user);
  // res.sendStatus(200);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)));

});
```

Comment: Is this specific to PUT? Does it go through with POST?  Also, just checking this route is a child of `api` and not just `user/:id`

Comment: I updated the code to have api/ in the beginning. You were right about that, but I'm still getting the same error. It needs to be a PUT request. I changed it to POST to test it, but that didn't work.

Comment: The email shouldn't be in th URL query string if the intent is to get it from body. ex URL: `http://localhost:3000/api/user/5dab496305de3025a09d31d`. ANd looking at screen grab from postman send body as `application/json` from right most menu and not as **Text**. And then check it out..if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use PUT, POST request because we don't want to reveal the user information through the URL and our motto is to hide the user information in the request body. We can use id's in URL that are unique strings but we should avoid the use of email in the URL itself.  Instead of this use json body :-

```
{
 newEmail: "abc@abc.com"
}
```

Get this ins code like this:-

```
req.body.newEmail
```

Here is your upadted code:-

```
app.put('/api/user/email/:id', (req, res) =>
User.update(
{id: req.params.id},
{email: req.body.newEmail}
).then( user => {
console.log(user);
res.json(user);
// res.sendStatus(200);
}).catch(err => console.log(err)));

});
```

In the postman, there is an option of passing the JSON body. You just have to select the body present below the URL test field and have to choose JSON type.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I added your updated code and tried, but I'm getting nModified: 0. Here's a postman reference: https://postimg.cc/cghDvnzb

Comment: There is a dropdown given at the rightmost in which text is selected. Click on the dropdown and select JSON from there.

Comment: [object Object] Use double quotes over newEmail also

Comment: I'm getting nModified: 0 with that postman config. Mongodb doesn't update

Comment: I have edited the code because your syntax for update mongo command is wrong. Please check updated code and then try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201855/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-andy).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass these through the url, you should use req.params.id, and req.params.email. You can use req.params.id and add it to the end of the url, and use req.body.newEmail in the body of your request.

This is a working example, you can modify it as seem fit.

```
router.put('/userinformation/incvh5/:id', (req, res) => 
User.update(
 {vh5rec: req.body.vh5rec},
 {where: {id: req.params.id}}
  ).then( user => {
  console.log(user);
  res.json(user);
  // res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

.catch(err => console.log(err)));

Comment: I tried adding email in the path like in the router.put example and I got nModified: 0. I'm closer, but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. updated postman: https://postimg.cc/rzyx8bNj

Comment: You need to do it like this, as im sure in your model your email datatype is a string. {"email":"newemail@email.com"}